# Get corresponding column to MAX value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, max, left-join

I don't understand what I need to do to get a value from a different column of a joined table when using MAX().

```
SELECT layout.NAME,layout.ID,MAX(inventory_reports.CLOSETIME)
              FROM layout
              LEFT JOIN inventory_reports ON layout.ID = inventory_reports.POSID
              WHERE layout.INVENTORY = 1 AND layout.AVAILABLE = 1
              GROUP BY layout.ID
              ORDER BY layout.NAME
```

The table `inventory_reports` also contains a column called `CLOSER`. How can I get that value for the row matching the `MAX(inventory_reports.CLOSETIME)` ?

I tried playing around with joining on subqueries, but all my attempts so far have given me incorrect results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT l.NAME,
       l.ID,
       ir1.MAX_CLOSETIME,
       ir2.CLOSER
FROM layout AS l
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT POSID, MAX(inventory_reports.CLOSETIME) AS MAX_CLOSETIME
   FROM inventory_reports
   GROUP BY POSID
) AS ir1 ON l.ID = ir1.POSID
LEFT JOIN inventory_reports AS ir2 
   ON ir1.POSID = ir2.POSID AND ir1.MAX_CLOSETIME = ir2.CLOSETIME
WHERE l.INVENTORY = 1 AND l.AVAILABLE = 1
ORDER BY l.NAME, l.ID
```

Comment: Yes. This worked. I'll have a closer look and see if I can understand what's going on here.

Comment: This question may have been a duplicate, but IMO - this was a more clearer solution to the OP's problem.

Comment: This will often work, but I think it relies on the assumption that there will not be two identical CLOSETIME for the same POSID.